# URL Encode string before using it in subsequent request (Gatling)

Tags: urlencode, gatling

I am making a call that responds with a (not URL-encoded) value.
I want to URL encode the value before making another request using this value in the URL like this:

```
  .exec(http("request_epj_ticket")
  .post("https://api.qa1.xxx:8000/v1/yyy/")
  .header("Authorization", "${authorizationHeader}")
  .headers(headers_0)
  .body(ElFileBody("bodies/epj_ticket_request.json"))
  .check(regex("ticket\" : \"(.*?)\"").saveAs("epj_ticket")))

.exec(session=>{
  println("epj_ticket:")
  println(session("epj_ticket").as[String])
  session})

//url-encoding here

/*
.exec(http("request_hentPasient_1")
  .get("https://qa1.xxx.html?ticket=${epj_ticket}")
  .headers(headers_1)
  .check(status.is(expected = 200)))
```

How do I make the last call using "epj-ticket" as url-encoded?

Comment: https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#query-parameters `.get("https://qa1.xxx.html").queryParam("ticket", "${epj_ticket}")`

Comment: but how to url code it?

Comment: ah, it works as you said, thanx!

Comment: To use the same concept for a headerMap (referer) it seems more difficult though. As in: "Referer"->"https://qa1.xxx/kj-innlogging/Innlogging/Innlogging.jsp?resource_url=https%3A%2F%2Fqa1.zzz%3A443%2Fhpp-webapp%xxx.html").queryParam("ticket", "${epj_ticket}"),